# How to set a xml layout as the view to a linear layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I am working on a project where I want to create two parts in a single page for example I would create a main page with the given parts (xml code below). It would be done on the `main_activity.xml` file and I want to set the view of the bottom `LinearLayout` to a different Layout Resource File. Which would contain some different codes. How can I achieve that?

```
 <RelativeLayout>
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:weightSum="2"

<LinearLayout>
                android:id="@+id/Top"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout>
                android:id="@+id/Bottom"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout/>
```

Comment: Don't understand what you want to do with your bottom layout

Comment: First of: Not sure the layout weights in your example work correctly... consider using a LinearLayout with a weightsum instead, with a vertical android:orientation... and then, make your linearlayouts below, have 0dp in height, in order for the weight to work as you want :)...Secondly: Have a look at the <include> control, which enables you to include a layout you are made, instead of the LinearLayout you are using now. Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understood your question from the post I suggest you to create separate layout for your bottom view and include it in your main xml layout file

Here if I want to add 2 top view and bottom view separately you can add 2 file in layout

let say i have tow layout file top_view.xml and bottom_view.xml

top_view.xml

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<Button
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="top button"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

bottom_view.xml

```
 <LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<Button
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="bottom button"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And in main_activiy.xml file include both file

main_activity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/d_scroll"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<include layout="@layout/top_view" />

<include
    layout="@layout/bottom_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

you can access all controls of included layout in main.java file